# How to implement a weighted mean squared error function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am defining a weighted mean squared error in Keras as follows:

```
def weighted_mse(yTrue,yPred):
    data_weights = [w0,w1,w2,w3]
    data_weights_np = np.asarray(data_weights, np.float32)
    weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(data_weights_np, np.float32)
    return K.mean(weights*K.square(yTrue-yPred))
```

I have a list of weights for each prediction. The predictions are of shape for example: (25,4). That is generated via final dense layer with dimension 4. I wish to weights these prediction in the mean squared error, so I generate a tensor and multiply it with the sum of squares error. Is this the correct way to do so? 
Because, when I print the shape of the tensor, using tf.shape for YTrue and YPred it shows:
`Tensor("loss_19/dense_20_loss/Shape:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)`

and for weights:

```
Tensor("loss_19/dense_20_loss/Shape_2:0", shape=(1,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: The [`fit`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) method has the parameters `class_weight` and `sample_weight` for that.

Answer (score 4):

The Keras API already provides a mechanism to provide weights, for example the `model.fit` function. From the [documentation](https://keras.io/models/model/):

> **class_weight:** Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.
>
> **sample_weight:** Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape  (samples, sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this case you should make sure to specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in compile().

If you have a weight for each sample, you can pass the NumPy array as `sample_weight` to achieve the same effect without writing your own loss function.

Comment: Apologies if it was not clear, I am looking something like class weight but for regression. There are 4 things I predict, and I want to weight these 4. Not samples.